# Magento 2.2.4 cart price rules - serious bugs in discount

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.4

I have created a cart price rule as per the following 2 pictures
[image: Allow discount only if items are from Category 3 and min qty in cart is 3]

[image: Apply discounts only if items are from Category 3]

When I added 3 items to the cart, the discount is given correctly
[image: Discount is given when qty of items is 3 or above]

However, when the quantity is changed to 2, the discount is still given to the customer, which is wrong.
[image]

Can anyone advise what I did wrong?

Comment: Even the quantity is changed to 2, your cart still met the condition. Why it's wrong? I think it's still correct

Comment: I see where I set wrong now. It took me asking this here, wasting your time for me to realise that I should have set it to 3 or greater instead of less. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: The rule condition is equals or less than 3.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. My bad on this. I wanted it to be 3 or more but made the mistake and did not realise it until now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you condition is **Total Items Quantity  equals or less than  3**

It means when you add < 4 total items quantity to cart, your cart rule validation will be true, so you will be received 30% discount as your **Actions** that you expected.

Try to add more items so that total items qty > 3 (in your examples above, your cart only had 2 or 3 items), and the discount amount will go away.

Cheers